# Возможно ли вернуть данные, преобразованные в даты Excel и запретить ему делать так?

Tags: excel, office

(не)Добрый день.

Сегодня утром обнаружил (тем самым голосом) *Surprise...*

Этот сюрприз заключался в том, что в одном из рабочих файлов excel часть чисел (вообще на другой странице, я эту страницу уже с неделю не открывал) стала датами...
Возможно ли как то:

1. Откатить преобразование? Т.е. вот у меня есть ячейки, в них были цифры, там, телефонные номера и.т.п., сейчас там даты. Можно ли как то эти даты вернуть в цифры как было? Или Excel их с концами убил самовольно? (то есть нет, я конечно сейчас посижу и из резервной копии восстановлю, к счастью там когда я проверял было все нормально, но сам факт, что вместо работы я сейчас буду сидеть и заниматься этим...)
2. Как то запретить Excel так делать? То есть вообще насовсем? Если чего, там у меня ВСЯ таблица, КАЖДЫЙ лист ЦЕЛИКОМ выбран текстовым форматом. Но он взял, и сделал даты. Посчитал что ему лучше знать... (А вот это самое главное, первый пункт можно и скипнуть)

PS использую Excel 2019 и да, я как тот чайник, под который разожгли огонь и он орет...

Comment: 1) Данные 99.9% необратимо разрушены. 2) А не ленитесь явно задавать форматы ячеек, не полагаясь на Default - это от него проблемы.

Comment: 2) Так я и не ленюсь... Явно это правой кнопкой мыши -> формат ячеек -> текстовый? Так я вроде как уже... Потому и говорю, что это был БОЛЬШОЙ сюрприз, обнаружить что эксель как то взял, и сделал...

Comment: *КАЖДЫЙ лист ЦЕЛИКОМ выбран текстовым форматом* - формат ячейки (визуальное отображение) и формат значения (реальное значение) - это совершенно разные форматы. Перед вставкой данных, похожих на даты, должен быть задан текстовый формат ячеек. Пример: 1/2 или 1.2 интерпретируются как 1 февраля или 2 января) Если формат ячеек был задан текстовым, значения вставлены корректно и сбой произошел позже - тут уже проблемы пользователя, сам Excel н мог преобразовать уже сохраненные данные.

Comment: Ну... Я хз как это могло быть, я тот лист давно уже не трогал, но когда последний раз трогал все выглядело нормально... По крайней мере я бы заметил что там большие жирные даты вместо цифр... То есть, я правильно понял, что запретить совсем с концами, вырубить, вырезать, уничтожить, аннигилировать формат дат и преобразование в них в экселе никак?

Comment: Последнее предположение полностью соответствует сегодняшнему положению дел - никак. Интернет переполнен воплями чайников и ветеранов - а в противовес одна невнятная [*инструкция*](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8) (типа, "мы сами не знаем поможет ли это..."). И да - мои соболезнования

Comment: Сейчас вот сижу перепроверяю файлы... Лучше уж сейчас потрачу время чем мне надо будет срочно, а там даты... Мб петицию запилить, что ли? Спасибо за соболезнования. =(

Comment: Возможно, с восстановлением первоначального вида данных поможет трюк с форматированием получившейся даты... Мне ни один из способов перечисленных [**здесь**](https://www.sql.ru/forum/120762-1/sos-excel-kak-zapretit-avto-preobrazovanie-teksta-v-datu) не помог на 100% - всегда данные портятся и всегда внезапно